# spark write data to hbase

Tags: apache-spark, hbase

I write a demo to write data to hbase, but  no response, no error, no log.
My hbase is 0.98, hadoop 2.3, spark 1.4.
And I run in yarn-client mode. any idea? thanks.

```
object SparkConnectHbase2 extends Serializable {

  def main(args: Array[String]) {
    new SparkConnectHbase2().toHbase();
  }

}

class SparkConnectHbase2 extends Serializable {

  def toHbase() {
    val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("ljh_ml3");
    val sc = new SparkContext(conf)

    val tmp = sc.parallelize(Array(601, 701, 801, 901)).foreachPartition({ a => 
      val configuration = HBaseConfiguration.create();
      configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.property.clientPort", "2181");
      configuration.set("hbase.zookeeper.quorum", “192.168.1.66");
      configuration.set("hbase.master", “192.168.1.66:60000");
      val table = new HTable(configuration, "ljh_test4");
      var put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(a+""));
      put.add(Bytes.toBytes("f"), Bytes.toBytes("c"), Bytes.toBytes(a + "value"));
      table.put(put);
      table.flushCommits();
    })

  }

}
```

thanks.

Comment: Did you find any solution on this?

Answer (score 0):

## Write to hbase table

```html
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.{HBaseAdmin, HTable, Put}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.{HBaseConfiguration, HTableDescriptor, HColumnDescriptor, TableName}
import org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableInputFormat
import org.apache.spark._
val hconf = HBaseConfiguration.create()
hconf.set(TableInputFormat.INPUT_TABLE, tablename)
val admin = new HBaseAdmin(hconf)
if(!admin.isTableAvailable(tablename)) {
    val tabledesc= new HTableDescriptor(tablename)
    tabledesc.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor("cf1".getBytes()));
    admin.createTable(tabledesc)
}
val newtable= new HTable(hconf, tablename);
val put = new Put(new String("row").getBytes());
put .add("cf1".getBytes(), "col1".getBytes(), new String("data").getBytes());
newtable.put(put);
newtable.flushCommits();
val hbaserdd = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(hconf, classOf[TableInputFormat],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.io.ImmutableBytesWritable],
      classOf[org.apache.hadoop.hbase.client.Result])
```